# OpenLayers5: GeoJSON: featureProjection vs dataProjection

Tags: openlayers, geojson

What's the difference between featureProjection and dataProjection in OpenLayers 5, GeoJSON class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data projection is the projection used to store the data (so the coordinates in your GeoJSON).

The feature projection is the projection used to display the data (so the view projection, likely 3857)